# JOOQ choose field Converter by another field

Tags: java, generics, jooq

I want to convert between Set of Enum POJO and String[] Database(postgres) column.
and the enum class would be changed by another field `type`.
So I can say Enum class which's using in `fooSet` is changable and it's up to field `type`.

I know it's a messy. but I need a help.

Below are models

```java
public interface A {

  enum B implements A {
    step1,
    step2,
    step3
  }

  enum C implements A {
    step4,
    step5,
    step6
  }
}
```

```java
public abstract class Foo {
  private String type;
}
```

```java
public abstract class FooA {
  private Set<B> fooSet;
}
```

```java
public abstract class FooB {
  private Set<C> fooSet;
}
```

I want to make a Converter like below.

```java
SetOfEnumConverter<U extends Enum<U> & A> implements Converter<String[], Set<U>> {

  @Override
  public Set<U> from(String[] databaseObject) {
    if (databaseObject == null) {
      return null;
    }
    return Arrays.stream(databaseObject)
        .map(x -> U.valueOf(U.class, x)).  // here's the problem point
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
  }

  @Override
  public String[] to(Set<U> userObject) {
    if (userObject == null || userObject.isEmpty()) {
      return null;
    }
    String[] strings = userObject.stream()
        .map(Enum::name)
        .toArray(String[]::new);
    return ArrayUtils.isEmpty(strings) ? new String[0]: strings;
  }

  @Override
  public Class<String[]> fromType() {
    return String[].class;
  }

  @Override
  public Class<Set<U>> toType() {
    return (Class) TreeSet.class;
  }
}
```

But the problem is I can't point `.class` attribute from a generic type maybe because of Generic Type erasure.

So, What I want to do is mapping the **setEnum** class to be used in the field **fooSet** according to the field **type**.
Because I have to **make a single table** for Foo and map from FooA, FooB and FooZ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this without passing an actual `Class<U>` reference to your converter, e.g. like this:

```java
SetOfEnumConverter<U extends Enum<U> & A> implements Converter<String[], Set<U>> {

    final Class<U> u;

    SetOfEnumConverter(Class<U> u) {
        this.u = u;
    }
    // ...
}
```

And inside of the converter, you can use:

```java
Enum.valueOf(u, x)
```

To look up arbitrary enum values by their names. Then, instantiate it with e.g.

```java
new SetOfEnumConverter<>(MyEnum.class);
```

Comment: what if `MyEnum.class` is dynamic?

Comment: @justzino: I don't know what you're actually doing, but I'm pretty sure that at some point, you can have access to such a `Class<U>` reference...